# Split large dataset into groups

Tags: r

My dataset has 2 columns and 300000 rows, in which it contains 1800 groups, I want to split the dataset by these groups and cbind them.

These groups might have different lengths.

Example

```
X<-data.frame(Dev=c("a","b","a","d","a"), value=(1,2,3,4,7))
Split<-split(X,f=X$Dev)
```

Then I have to cbind these lists.

Since I have huge dataset, I can't extract each list from list. Since each has different lengths, so it's not allowing to directly use function `cbind(Split)`.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the max number of rows from the entire list and append `NA`'s for list with shorter length.

```
n <- 1:max(sapply(Split, nrow))
result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(Split, `[`, n, ))
result

#  a.Dev a.value b.Dev b.value d.Dev d.value
#1     a       1     b       2     d       4
#3     a       3  <NA>      NA  <NA>      NA
#5     a       7  <NA>      NA  <NA>      NA
```

**data**

```
X<-data.frame(Dev=c("a","b","a","d","a"), value=c(1,2,3,4,7))
Split<-split(X,f=X$Dev)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your expected outcome is a dataframe you can easily do this with `pivot_wider()`

```
library(tidyr)

X %>% 
    rowid_to_column() %>%  
    pivot_wider(names_from = Dev, values_from = value) %>% 
    select((-rowid))
```

If your true dataframe has more than two columns you could omit the `row_id` part. See [the documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) for more examples.